# C# COM object invoked by C++ unmanaged code

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, clr

I have an unmanaged-code C++ EXE which runs and invokes a C# COM object by class ID using CoCreateInstance.

When the code inside the C# COM object runs, I can use the .Net libraries with no issues.

Can anybody explain the threading model that would be working in this instance, is the code running in the C# component fully managed with GC?  I find spawning new threads doesn't really work, or reports the same managed thread ID each time.

Comment: The threading model in COM is not a subtle detail.  Default registration for a [ComVisible] assembly is "Both".  What you are willing to support is what you specify in your CoInitializeEx() call.  Seeing all calls execute on the same thread on which you created the object is normal, that is required STA behavior and what you get when you pass COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED.

Comment: As i understand this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3(v=vs.110).aspx, you can't specify exact threading model on managed server, it depends from c++ client, how client initializes connection, in other words from the second parameter of CoInitializeEx()